# Is there a way to show how long an SD card has been in a device?

Tags: sd-card

How can I prove the SD card I'm using in my fire 5th generations DID not come out of the Galaxy my boyfriend has. I bought my fire used on eBay and the SD was left /forgot in it.Is there a way my device has something stored in it that would prove its been I'm here for months? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the card has data from before the alleged event & that data is relevant to the fire but not to the phone, you could simply check file/folder creation dates on any computer.

If it was formatted after your key time, then nothing can be proven either way.